# FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb**** is not registered as a URL Scheme

Tags: ios6, facebook-login

I want to have the `Facebook app native dialog login` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/iossdk/login/#fbnative).

In the console, I get the following message when clicking on the FBLoginView:

```
FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb**** is not registered as a URL Scheme
```

Yet I did exactly as here: [Failing to open active session after updating Facebook SDK to 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113688/failing-to-open-active-session-after-updating-facebook-sdk-to-3-5)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In `myapp-Info.plist`, I renamed `URL Schemes` key  to `CFBundleURLSchemes`:

Before:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>URL Schemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb***</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

After:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb***</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The difference is not visible in XCode because `CFBundleURLSchemes` is aliased with `URL Schemes`.

As a consequence, you have to edit `myapp-Info.plist` manually.

Comment: This seems to be such an odd problem.

Comment: Worked for me but I had to change URL Type to CFBundleUrlTypes as well

Comment: Didn't work for me. Probably would be helpful to see where the root node sits in the .plist file.

Comment: worked for me ! But I don't understand why, can someone explain to me plz ? Why CFBundleURLSchemes is aliased ? I'm new to Xcode/iOS

Answer (score 30):

The problem is in the plist file as it needs different settings then it was published in official Facebook video and articles for Facebook SDK 3.5.x.

If you'd like to use 2 or more apps with the same Facebook AppID - which is useful as all the activity, posts will cumulate under the same Facebook appearance for all version like premium or lite - but in this case you have to solve somehow that Facebook calls back (URL scheme) the correct app from where the user came from and the user could continue to use our app when finished with the Facebook activity, like post etc.

So we have to use URL types and URL Schemes in the Xcode and in the Facebook Developer settings as you can see on the illustrations below:

> **UPDATE 2015**

I have updated the screenshots to reflect the new Facebook and Xcode settings:

**Xcode 6**

As you can see you have to use the FacebookAppID with the attached URL Scheme Suffix and the same FacebookDisplayName **BUT** you have to use the "fb" prefix in the URL types-->URL Schemes line and use the FacebookDisplayName in the Identifier line, see below. This will ensure that Facebook will call back the correct app (lite or premium in this example) but all the post etc will go to the same Facebook app.

[image]

**Facebook**

> iPhone Store ID is for the premium version as we'd like to route the
>   user to the paid version!

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In my app, the error was caused because the case of the property keys was incorrect.

They should be:

URL types (lowercase T)

URL Schemes (uppercase S)

Comment: OMG, thanks, I was going nuts trying to figure this one out, I had a lower case s for schemes!!

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution for us:

We had two URL schemes defined. One for our app "ourapp://" and one for facebook "fb123456789".

As it turns out, the facebook URL has to be number one.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by removing the space i had between fb and my app ID in the info.plist

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem (Facebook SDK 3.5.1)

My URL scheme for Facebook was on Item 1. Problem fixed by moving it to Item 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try FBConnect

you can find thorough how to here:

http://mobisoftinfotech.com/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: This is exactly what I already have: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Picture-111.png, i.e. a UIWebView overlay. I want an iOs native login: https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/851581_643828892298304_190220435_n.png

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had the `FBAppID` pasted in 3x times and it was only apparent by inspecting the `.plist` file with a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Facebook SDK v.3 or more, I have found problem with open Facebook Login. when I click on the Login button then not open the popup  screen for user Login.

So, below is the solution for this issue :

When I change the system Date & Time from previous to the current and again check the application and it's works perfect. so please check the device's Date & Time.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.
So, i try copy item 0 : fb1234567890 to item 1 : fb1234567890

Array URL Schemes have 2 item: item 0, item 1
It's OK.
hope it good for you!