# Facebook App ID for multiple Apps

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Do I need a unique Facebook App ID for every single App or could I use the Facebook App ID for multiple Apps.

Comment: this question is highly ambiguous.

Comment: You could see a detailed illustration with the updated 2015 version for Xcode 6 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18480723/1780492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A unique app must have a unique ID, isn't it?

So, yes each app has a unique App ID; but for different platforms but same app, a single App ID is used.