# FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fbxxxx is not registered as a URL Scheme

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

I have read a variety of similar posts on Stack Overflow, but none of them solved my problem. I have verified that my app id is indeed correct. I tried opening the .plist in a text editor and changing the URL Scheme to CFBundleURLSchemes, but that didn't solve the issue either. Is there a reason this is occurring in the simulator?

None of the suggestions here helped;
[FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb**** is not registered as a URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132003/fbsdklog-cannot-use-the-facebook-app-or-safari-to-authorize-fb-is-not-regi)

Comment: So you have the correct fbxxx (xxx being the app id) as CFBundleURLSchemes and also both those keys defined `<key>FacebookAppID</key>` `<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>` ?

Comment: You could see a detailed illustration with the updated 2015 version for Xcode 6 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18480723/1780492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the fb app installed on the simulator?.. if NOT there is no URL scheme registered
You must have the app to make url scheme work =)

GL HF

Comment: I think there is just no way to getthe app on the simulator ... you will have to test with a real device

Comment: Ah okay this makes sense. So I shouldn't worry about this error then right(if it works on a device)?

Comment: yeah I think you should not worry =) ... users will use devices.. not simulators =D

Comment: I am able to sign in to FB using simulator, but my problem occurs in real devices where FB account is not signed in at the phones "settings-facebook" thought Facebook app was signed in.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with simulator always and sometimes in real devices where Facebook was not signed under the phone "Settings".

Following the below answer links "Accepted answer" and also referring to "FB getting started" document solved my problem. Hope it will help you too.

[Facebook SDK: app not registered as a URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893447/facebook-sdk-app-not-registered-as-a-url-scheme)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started 
(Topic: Configure an Xcode Project)

Comment: by the way you do not have to have FB App installed for this to work