# Facebook SDK: app not registered as a URL Scheme

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin, url-scheme

I am using the `Facebook SDK` found [here](http://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios), and am trying the sample that is provided (in the folder `FacebookiOSSample`).

If I simply replace the `AppId` here with my specific `AppId`, then I can no longer Share. (I replaced it in both the `AppDelegate` file and the `info.plist` file). I now receive the following error:

> FBSDKLog: Invalid use of FBAppCall, fb**** is not registered as a URL
>   Scheme. Did you set 'FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix' in your plist?

Otherwise this works fine with the sample's original `AppId` which points to something named `IFaceTouch`.

What could be wrong with the setup of my app, how do I register my `AppId`?

Comment: Note: The answer below that advises you to add fbauth2 to your CFBundleURLSchemes will cause your app to intercept other app's Facebook app-switch login traffic. *DO NOT DO THIS*

Comment: If you are trying to resolve "canOpenURL: failed" warnings, those only indicate that the Facebook app is not installed on your device or simulator and can be ignored.'

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Follow these three steps:

1. Create a key called **FacebookAppID** with a string value, and add the app ID there.
2. Create a key called **FacebookDisplayName** with a string value, and add the Display Name you configured in the App Dashboard.
3. Create an array key called URL types with a single array sub-item called **URL Schemes**. Give this a single item with your app ID prefixed with fb. This is used to ensure the application will receive the callback **URL** of the web-based OAuth flow.

The finished .plist should look something like this:

[image]

[Source Link:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/)

Comment: Okay the problem seemed to be FacebookDisplayName, this was not matching my App Dashboard. Thanks!

Comment: Most case the typo which could cause similar error message, even a mistyped letter with missed upper/lower case. Double check them!

Comment: @BootMaker Second that - Mine wasn't working because I incorrectly had "URL schemes" instead of "URL Schemes".

Comment: You could see a detailed illustration with the updated 2015 version for Xcode 6 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18480723/1780492

Comment: Also be careful to have the FacebookAppID and FacebookDisplayName upper than the URL types. It crashes if not so on SDK 4.

Comment: if someone using Google sign in, then there will be another URL Scheme for the google as well. so there will be two items in the array

Comment: In one URL type you can have more than one URL Scheme (ie. when using different environments)

Answer (score 24):

[image: In terms of raw keys and values you should have CFBundleURLTypes and CFBundleURLSchemes]

In terms of raw keys and values you should have CFBundleURLTypes and CFBundleURLSchemes. Hope that helps!

Comment: CFBundle is exists, but the xml format helped me to find that my structure was wrong. thank you

Answer (score 22):

there is another section below the info - **URL Types**

check that the values there, under the *URL Schemes* field match the value in the ***URL types -> URL Schemes*** in the property list above.
(and also match the FacebookAppID)

[image: URL TYPES]

Answer (score 10):

**For iOS 9**

If you have an error: 'LSApplicationQueriesSchemes'

Based on [Bear with me answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21893768/2629814), you will also have to add those lines:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
   <string>fbauth2</string>
</array>
```

See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9#whitelistapp).

You *should* end up with those lines at the end of your .plist files:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb2R3234544534554</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>2R3234544534554</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>stevejeff</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
    </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

*** If you're using v4.6.0 or higher of the SDK, you only need to add:*** (Thanks  [mohsinj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/928599/mohsinj))

```
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
   </array>
```

Comment: [UPDATE] Aug - 2016 For "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" You have to add more items - 
`<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>`

Answer (score 9):

1- In Xcode, right-click your project's Info.plist file and select Open As -> Source Code.

2- Insert the following XML snippet into the body of your file just before the final `</dict>` element.

```
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb{your-app-id}</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{your-app-id}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{your-app-name}</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

3- Replace {your-app-id}, and {your-app-name} with your app's App's ID and name found on the Facebook App Dashboard.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using multiple social auths then place URL schema like as below.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb7876940600009</string>
   <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.76235222224-hfvusdel7p8eavfvn</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>7876983017</string>
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>
<string>e29fbf1f15a5b5be028dcb</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>xdfxdffmate</string>
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to this [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=ios) Select Your App, And configure your `info.plist`

Answer (score 4):

Had this issue but was because i missed the prefix `fb` with the app id for the url scheme section.

Answer (score 1):

Today i solved this bug by just removing space from **FacebookDisplayName**.

make sure you don't have any space in **FacebookDisplayName**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your problem is the same as mine. But it took me some time to find it and i will put it here so that it can help anyone.. The problem was that google sign in used the same info.plist attribute name and it was overriding the ones of facebook.. So i could see this in X-Code and put them together, now everything works fine! (URL Types attribute).

Answer (score 1):

In my case i already had LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and CFBundleURLTypes keys in my info.plist, When I again added them separately in info.plist. it didn't read the second one and doesn't recognize. So add values into the previous LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and CFBundleURLTypes keys solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

if you used login with google and implemented already put both in same url schema

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
   <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>https</string>
            <string>fbXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string> //facebook app id
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string> // Google Url Schemal
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these three steps:**

1. Create a key called **FacebookAppID** with any string value, and add the **app ID** there.
2. Create a key called **FacebookDisplayName** with a string value, and add the **Display Name** you configured in the App Dashboard.
3. Create an array key called **URL types** with a single array sub-item called URL Schemes. Give this a single item with your **app ID prefixed with fb**. This is used to ensure the application will receive the callback URL of the web-based OAuth flow.

**Final info.plist**
[image: Final info.plist]

result:
[image]
[image]
Reference: https://github.com/darwin-morocho/flutter-facebook-auth/blob/master/examples/with_provider/ios/Runner/Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue in my react native app.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>fb23456789032432</string>. ------> Fixed it by just adding fb before App ID
</array>
</dict>
</array>

<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>23456789032432</string>
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>
<string>02223330beb0a72348c45bf34969bd1b</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>App Name</string>
```