# Facebook iOS SDK: Multiple Facebook apps for different environments

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode5, facebook-ios-sdk

We are building an app that uses the newest Facebook iOS SDK (3.15) for iOS 7 on Xcode 5. There is an associated web product, and we use 3 environments for deployment: production, staging, and development. We have a separate Facebook app for each of these environments, which is well documented and works well on web. However, Facebook's iOS SDK requires specifying `FacebookAppID`, `FacebookDisplayName`, and `URL Schemes` in our `Info.plist` file. Our mobile app is also set up with the 3 environments, using a different Configuration for each environment. I haven't been able to get the Facebook SDK to play nice with Configuration-specific values in our `Info.plist` file.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction for setting up multiple iOS app environments with multiple Facebook apps?

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: @Esq I faced with the same issue recently, please check my answer below

Comment: @Esq I just posted my answer using a different strategy than Azat. Check below, sorry for the delay and hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

I used a different strategy than Azat, which worked for iOS 7/8 and Facebook iOS SDK v3.21. Because I had multiple settings beyond just Facebook that were environment-specific, I created a generic Singleton to handle environment configurations. Here are the steps:

**1. Create Configurations for App**

Go to your Project Settings, Info tab, and create configurations for each different environment. I personally used `Development`, `Staging`, `Release`, and `Debug` (last 2 both for Production environment).

**2. Expose Configuration Name in Info.plist**

In your app's `Info.plist` file, create a key called `Configuration` and set the value to `${CONFIGURATION}`.

**3. Build Singleton to Handle Environment Configuration**

The full code can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hspinks/c313d00cb10e5c8baf14), but here's the gist (no pun intended) of it. You'll create an additional property list `Environments.plist` with a key for each configuration whose value is a dictionary containing all of your environment-specific settings. Next you'll build an `Environment` class that will have a singleton instance through which you can expose those settings. Essentially you can call `[[Environment sharedInstance] facebookAppId]` from anywhere in your app that you've imported `Environment.h`, which we will do in the next step.

**4. Explicitly choose Facebook appId and displayName in Your App Delegate**

In your `AppDelegate.m`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, the very first lines should read:

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:[[Environment sharedInstance] facebookAppId]];
[FBSettings setDefaultDisplayName:[[Environment sharedInstance] facebookDisplayName]];
```

**5. Add Facebook URL Schemes to Info.plist**

In your `Info.plist`, you'll need to add the URL Schemes for each Facebook app you are using for all of your environments. See the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21893768/2434476), but instead of just 1 item under `URL Schemes`, you'll have 1 for each environment.

**6. Choose Configuration in Scheme**

To run using a certain configuration, edit your scheme (`⌘+<` shortcut on Mac) and choose your configuration. To make it easier to not have to edit every time I ran, I created a scheme for each of my environments with the proper configuration already chosen for Run, Test, Profile, and Archive.

---

This was last tested on iOS 8 and Facebook iOS SDK v3.21, but I'm hoping the general strategy here can apply to iOS 9 and later versions of the Facebook iOS SDK. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can add new `target` to your project, select `OS X` > `Other` > `External Build System` and use `/usr/bin/python` as build tool.

Then, in Build Settings, add User-Defined Setting, `FB_APP_ID` and set IDs of your apps for different build configurations (`Debug`/`Release`/etc).

In the Info tab, in the `Arguments` field enter the following

```
fbupdate.py $(FB_APP_ID)
```

Here is the `fbupdate.py` script:

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
import sys

from lxml.etree import tostring, parse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fb_app_id = None
    new_fb_app_id = sys.argv[1]

    filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'TargetName', 'Info.plist')

    tree = parse(filename)

    for el in tree.xpath('//plist/dict/key[text()="FacebookAppID"]'):
        value_el = el.getnext()
        fb_app_id = value_el.text
        value_el.text = new_fb_app_id
        break

    for el in tree.xpath('//array/string[text()="fb{fb_app_id}"]'.format(
            fb_app_id=fb_app_id)):
        el.text = 'fb' + new_fb_app_id
        break

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(tostring(tree, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True).encode('utf8'))

    print('FB App ID update done.')
```

I use `Scripts` folder inside the root folder of my project, so I specify it in the Directory field. If you have different location, don't forget to change the script to open the correct `Info.plist` file. Also you will need to replace `TargetName` in the script to your original target.

Then, go to your original target settings and in the `Build Phases` add the Target Dependencies to that new created `External Build System` target.

Now this python script will run **before** the build of your original target and put the correct Facebook App ID to the `Info.plist` and it will be that ID which you need in your current build configuration.

P.S. You may need to run `pip install lxml` from terminal and/or install any other dependencies to make that script run on your machine

P.P.S. I know it may be too late for original question, but it may be useful for others