# How to set FacebookDisplayName?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I recently hit a problem while trying to integrate FaceBook in an iOS app.
Fortunately I found the answer here:
[Facebook SDK: app not registered as a URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893447/facebook-sdk-app-not-registered-as-a-url-scheme)

This is where I have a question:
In the post mentioned above the answer gives the following as the second step:

**Create a key called FacebookDisplayName with a string value, and add the Display Name you configured in the App Dashboard.**

How do I write this Display Name in case it is changing according to the user Language Settings?
I tried ${DisplayName} or ${CFBundleDisplayName} but I have no confidence I am using the right syntax and name.

Comment: did you find the answer to this?

Comment: I found the answer, or found a way around. I do not remember of hand as it was a while ago. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the InfoPlist.strings you can add

> FacebookDisplayName = "AppName";

for all the languages you have implemented. This way it will be consistent to the facebook configured details regardless of what your app is really called on the device.