# Facebook iOS SDK 4.2: Invalid URL Schemes for Multiple App Environments

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk, url-scheme

I need to use the same Facebook App ID for my `staging` and `production` builds. I've defined the URL schemes suffix in my app `.plist` file and configured the dashboard with the required Bundle Id and URL schemes ,following exactly as [sharing an app ID across Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting) doc.

**Dashboard's URL scheme suffix:**

[image]

**App-Info.plist:**

[image]

The thing is , I am able to login with Facebook on my `staging` build properly but when I try to login on `production` build, it crashes and breaks at the following:

[image]

I've tried some of the almost similar solutions, but none of it is working for me. Can someone point me in the right direction?

- [Facebook SDK: app not registered as a URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893447/facebook-sdk-app-not-registered-as-a-url-scheme)
- [FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb**** is not registered as a URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132003/fbsdklog-cannot-use-the-facebook-app-or-safari-to-authorize-fb-is-not-regi/18480723#18480723)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it solved. As it turns out, I can only define one FB URL Scheme per scheme. I also forgot to define `FacebookURLSchemeSuffix`. So, what I did is, I use user-defined setting to alternate between `staging` and `production` build. Here's how I did it.

1. Go to `Targets > Build Setttings` and add `user-defined setting`.

[image]

Then, I set my user-defined values(`FB_SCHEME`) to `staging` for `staging` build and vice versa.

1. In my `App-info.plist` file. I set my `FacebookURLSchemeSuffix` and `URL scheme` to the following:

[image]
[image]

Now, whenever I switch between schemes, it will set the value of `${FB_SCHEME}` to `production` or `staging`. That's it.

Comment: You can have multiple fb{app_id}{suffix} schemes defined in one Info.plist file, you just need to specify the correct FacebookURLSchemeSuffix for different apps.