# Deeplinking from Facebook Call-to-Action Button not working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking, facebook-call-to-action

I created a call-to-action button "Use App" on our Facebook page with the links to the Play Store, AppStore and the custom url scheme. The scheme works fine when I enter it in Safari on iOS but by clicking the "Use App"-link in Facebook I only get redirected to the shop and not in the installed app.

Is there any way to debug what facebook is sending back? I tried Facebooks Graph Tool with

```
curl -i -X GET \ "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/109949472360983?fiels=app_links&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN`
```

but that only doesn't return what i expect.

Comment: If I would have to guess I'd say this is due to the recent changes in iOS9 where an app has to explicitly define which URL schemes it wants to query for. If you have the chance, try it on iOS8 and see if it works there. If yes, this is most likely the issue you are facing.

Comment: Hi Björn and thanks for your answer. I tried it yesterday but no luck. I found an interesting article on [blog.branch.io](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-deep-link-on-facebook) about deeplinks on Facebook that says it am not supposed to provide an actual link but meta data on my website

Comment: Hm, so I just tried it with the fb{APP-ID} URL scheme by setting the CTA target to App and then just entered the deeplink (example fb1234567890://foo/bar) and it worked fine for me. Did you use a custom URL scheme that is not the one FB automatically generates?

Comment: So thanks to Björn I created the app on facebook and added the fb{APP-ID} URL scheme and with that the call-to-action button works like expected. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893447/facebook-sdk-app-not-registered-as-a-url-scheme) was really helpful too