# What is the iOS URL schema for Facebook profiles?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class func openFacebook(id: String){ //id is a username in this case
    let name = id.replace(" ", withString: "")
    let hook = "fb://profile/" + name
    let hookURL = NSURL(string: hook)
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(hookURL!){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(hookURL!)
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://facebook.com/" + name)!)
    }
}
```

I try to do this, but it never opens the app. It always opens the browser.
I'm not using the facebook sdk. I just want to open facebook from my app, to the user's profile.

Comment: Any messages in the console when you run this code? Did you add the `fb` scheme to the list of allowable schemes your app can access?

Comment: No, I didn't add fb scheme to list of allowable schemes. However, I also have similar code for instagram/twitter -- and those work, and I didn't add those to plist either.

Comment: They won't work under iOS 9 or later.

Comment: I'm on iOS 10, and every scheme works except for fb.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10) post might help you.

Answer (score 7):

The iOS URL schema goes like this:

```
fb://profile?id=[username|user_id]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an error: 'LSApplicationQueriesSchemes'
so you have to register url scheme in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes under plist.

please check below link for process of adding url scheme to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

[Facebook SDK: app not registered as a URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893447/facebook-sdk-app-not-registered-as-a-url-scheme)