# FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize,

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I deploy my application to the real device I got "FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb6262xxxxxxx is not registered as a URL Scheme"
I followed all the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132003/fbsdklog-cannot-use-the-facebook-app-or-safari-to-authorize-fb-is-not-regi) thread without fixing the issue

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem and I got the work around for this.

Please see the below screenshot for this.

[image]

Use fb in Item 0

This Works for me. I hope it would work for you too.

Comment: For anybody confused with this answer like I was: the string "fb.***" is found in the error message.